# Replant branch?

Tags: identification, trees, tree-care, growth, transplanting

I live in the Caribbean, and while riding bike, I saw this tree:
[image]

So I cut a small branch:
[image]

Can I replant this branch? Can it somehow be replanted in a pot?

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up putting it in a bowl of water. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

From your pictures, it looks the leaves are from two different plants.

the top one is probably some species of lagerstromeria, maybe L. speciosa.....around here, they're called crepe myrtles.

the second pic is from something else, the leaves are completely different....maybe an albizia or acacia.  Looks very much like an alibizia, except for the seed pods.  If it is an albizia, it may be very difficult to propagate from cuttings

Comment: looks like the cutting is from a royal poinciana, after consideratoin

Answer (score 0):

It may need some rooting compound, and to prevent dehydration you should remove the leaves, but you're on the right track.